# Yank / copy / get into a buffer matching regex search results

Tags: search, occur

I am trying to "extract" my search results into a new buffer, but only the matches - not the whole lines.

For example I am trying to get a list of HTML color codes used in a file. I can identify them (in this case) with a search for `"#.*?"`, which produces:

[image]

However, now I want all those matches copied into a new buffer to work on. I just can't seem to figure out how to do this?

Comment: What are you going to do with them after you edit them? Will you be returning the modified codes to the original file?

Comment: No - importing them into a reference document for a style guide.

Comment: In other words, I don’t need to “return” them. I’m just trying to get a list of them easily. I can actually do this very easily in Sublime - but I’d like to understand the emacs or evil way to do it (if there is one).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`C-u M-x occur \"\(#[^\"]+\)\" <RETURN> \1`

(this strips the quotes)

or

`C-u M-x occur "#.+\" <RETURN>`

(this keeps the quotes)

`occur` finds all lines that match the provided regexp. Calling it with the prefix argument (`C-u`) returns *only* the matched text, not the complete lines. Using the capture group (`\(...\)`) lets you select the group, while ignoring the enclosing quotes. If you don't care about including the quotes, you can drop the capture group.

For example:

```
(let (
      (base00 "#081724")
      (base01 "#033340")
      (base02 "#1d5483")
      (base03 "#2872b2")
      (base04 "#d3f9ee")
      (base05 "#a6f3dd")
      (base06 "#effffe")
      (base07 "#fffed9")
      (red "#ff694d")
      (orange "#f5b55f")
      (yellow "#fffe4e")
      (magenta "#afc0fd")
      (violet "#96a5d9")
      (blue "#bad6e2")
      (cyan "#d2f1ff")
      (green "#68f6cb")
      (twsblue "#0000ff"))
```

Calling `occur` as above produces:

```
#081724
#033340
#1d5483
#2872b2
#d3f9ee
#a6f3dd
#effffe
#fffed9
#ff694d
#f5b55f
#fffe4e
#afc0fd
#96a5d9
#bad6e2
#d2f1ff
#68f6cb
#0000ff
#002b36
```

Comment: Thanks, this answered my question. I'm only 5 days into emacs, so I had never even heard of the prefix argument - thanks for that. For any that follow, I often want to do this immediately after doing a / search. I wrapped a function to make this work using the last thing you searched for (note, I'm using evil, so you might need to tweak the reference to the search pattern if not): https://gist.github.com/mtwomey/629bb4b2163450117b7a4c8fdcc8eb4a